# Debug PHP as CGI

Tags: php, debugging, cgi

what opportunities there are to debug PHP as CGI?
I find with Google or very little help here.

I receive following error (log) 
FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server

But thats too less. I need more information.

Comment: we need more information from you too. What is your scenario? Debug with PHP as CGI ?

Comment: It is a message from apache log. We generate a report file and during this process the CGI Error appears. It works fine on other servers, but not on this and i want to debug it or "activate the super information config switch" or something. The error is not really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to debug PHP is using [`xdebug`](http://xdebug.org/) extension on server. Many debuggers support `xdebug` out of box. Eclipse can be [configured to use `xdebug`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug) to debug PHP scripts, but I personally prefer to use [Komodo IDE](http://activestate.com/komodo) (commercial, but works great).